# I cannot identify english words in the song

Tags: listening

What words are said at the begining of the song
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOUtGP2UuS0&list=PLCDB3A4909F61CA29&index=16 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the song is "Cost of Freedom" and the words are a sample of U.S. President John F. Kennedy's [Cuban Missile Crisis Address](https://www.americanrhetoric.com/speeches/jfkcubanmissilecrisis.html). He says "**the cost of freedom is always high**." You can hear the original at the link I provided --it's just after minute 17:00 in the recording.

Comment: Such a different sound from Kennedy's speech for my ears

Comment: @xyz, Yes, it's a very different listening experience! I think the sound editor has likely made some changes to the speed and pitch of the clip, but it's hard to tell with the background track behind it.